# php,Paypal for making payments for customer

Tags: php, paypal

i am currently working in one project which provides various services to customers and customer have to paid for usage of services but still now i have no use any services of  Paypal for making payments and now i want to add the Paypal for payments option so please kindly help me or give any link or material for adding this capability.
i have heard about sandbox but i don't know how to use it so if any know about it suggest me

thanks

Comment: try [this](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should read about IPN https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [paypal developer site](http://developer.paypal.com/), it will give you both Documentation and sandbox to test  you can also find sample php code on github on [this link](https://github.com/paypal?query=php)